# Number of Processors in Clojure? Java interop

Tags: java, performance, clojure, interop

I'd like to use the Java method:  `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and save the result in a integer variable.

So in Clojure I did this:

```
(def n-cpu  ((.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)) ))
```

and this:

```
(def n-cpu (Integer/parseInt ((.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)) )))
```

but none work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you replace the method call in your version with an integer, this is what you logically have:

```
(def n-cpu (4))
```

Clojure cannot handle the list `(4)` because the first item in a non-quoted list must be a function. In this case the first item is an integer, and Clojure doesn't treat integers as functions. If you remove the unnecessary parentheses, your var definition would look like this:

```
(def n-cpu (.availableProcessors (Runtime/getRuntime)))
```

Notice how if you replace the method call with an integer, it becomes `(def n-cpu 4)`?